# SQL statement execution error say incorrect sunataxt near '_HP_KYCMS18837P51144'

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Any suggestion to fix below issue will be appreciated.

I am trying to run sql statement using java where I have dynamic file name all the time For example this time my full file name is `"WTX-5010_HP_KYCMS18837P51144.txt"`

This is my sql statement: `SELECT processid, *  FROM [Config].[AD].[FILELOG] where filename='WTX-5010_HP_KYCMS18837P51144.txt'

Following is my script:

```
    static String NewFileNmae = WTX-5010_HP_KYCMS18837P51144.txt;

                System.out.println("Full New File Name is " + NewFileNmae);


                try {

String strpQuery2 = "SELECT processid, *  FROM [Config].[AD].[FILELOG] where filename=";

                    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+strpServer+":"+strpPort+";databaseName="+strpDatabase+";IntegratedSecurity=true";

                    // Declare the JDBC objects.  
                    Connection con = null;  
                    Statement stmt = null;  
                    ResultSet rs = null;  

                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  

                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 



                    String SQLS = strpQuery2+NewFileNmae;
                    System.out.println("SQLQuery is " + SQLS);
                    stmt = con.createStatement();  
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLS);  

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        ProcessID = rs.getString(1);

                        System.out.println("List value are " +ProcessID);

                    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

In the debug window I can see that sql statement printed as `"SELECT processid, *  FROM [Config].[AD].[FILELOG] where filename=WTX-5010_HP_KYCMS18837P51144.txt"` till this point in the above script `rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLS)`;

However, on F6 action after `rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLS) it fail and produce following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '_HP_KYCMS18837P51144'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
    at Test.TS01ClaimLoadverifyClaimLoadsuccessHCFA.verifyClaimLoadsuccessHCFA(TS01ClaimLoadverifyClaimLoadsuccessHCFA.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at TestScriptRunner.Runner.runTestScriptKeywords(Runner.java:856)
    at TestScriptRunner.Runner.triggerRun(Runner.java:344)
    at TestScriptRunner.Runner.main(Runner.java:144)
    at Test.TestScriptRun.main(TestScriptRun.java:9)
```

I am adding file name as variable where when dynamic file name is autogenerated then it is not bringing quote '' along with file name. How can I mention single quot to  NewFileName variable here? - String SQLS = strpQuery2+NewFileNmae;

Comment: Is the String "NewFileNmae " correctly pasted at the top of your code? It wouldn't even compile. the way it is

Comment: read about prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string should wrapped between quote  `'WTX-5010_HP_KYCMS18837P51144.txt'` (you missed)

```
SELECT processid, *  
FROM [Config].[AD].[FILELOG] 
where filename= 'WTX-5010_HP_KYCMS18837P51144.txt'


"SELECT processid, *  FROM [Config].[AD].[FILELOG] where filename='" + ;
 NewFileNmae +"';"
```

Comment: static String NewFileNmae = WTX-5010_HP_KYCMS18837P51144.txt; and String strpQuery2 = "SELECT processid, *  FROM [Config].[AD].[FILELOG] where filename="; then how to mention here  String SQLS = strpQuery2+NewFileNmae; with single quote?

Comment: what do you mean with your comment  ?  . . be sure that your filename is enclosed  in quote (your statement is not)   otherwise the sql fails ..

Comment: Although this may work, it is fundamentally unsafe to just concatenate string values into a query string. The OP should use a prepared statement and set the value as a parameter.